# Is it advisable to create a request context with ThreadLocal on the Spark framework

Tags: spark-java

Using the [Spark web framework](http://sparkjava.com) - I'd like to avoid passing all parameters into every method signature (request user, etc). Is it suitable to use a context with static `ThreadLocal` properties?

I guess we don't have full control which thread services a request but guess Initializing with each call on the Spark API/boundary should be fine.

Comment: Maybe you could store information like userId in the session

Comment: If I'm not using session at all though (stateless server), can I use ThreadLocal to store stuff, as per suggested? I've used that before on other frameworks structure, but I'd like to know if Spark would have any problem with it (like thread sharing or something, which would be actually good for performance). Or can I use the request.session anyway, even though I'm not using session, only drawback being it will be reset every request (just as I wanted)? Or are there other caveats involved?

Answer (score 1):

I fiddled around a bit and I think I found a good solution for this problem. According to the documentation:

```
/**
 * Sets an attribute on the request
 * (can be fetched in filters/routes later in the chain)
 *
 * @param attribute The attribute
 * @param value     The attribute value
 */
public void attribute(String attribute, Object value) {
    /* ... */
}
```

So you can use set an attribute in the request itself and later fetch it. Pretty neat.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to pass the request into the business logic and create a dependency on the web library.

Comment: That makes sense; in my case I'd only use this data in the controllers, that already had access to the object.